Difference between 時限目 and 時限
Based on my understanding, when talking about class periods, N時限 means "N periods" while N時限目 means "Nth period." However I sometimes encounter situations when the former N時限 actually means "Nth period" not "N periods." I wonder it is true and if so, how it is different from N時限目?
Here are some examples that shows N時限 sometimes means "Nth period":

From one of the mangas I am reading: 4限が長引いてさー遅くなったわ

Example sentence from Jiisho: 1時限は何の授業ですか



Closely related: Leaving away the 目 suffix for ordinal numbers

It may vary across institutions, but as living language I only hear n時限 as "n period(s)" and 第n時限 or n時限目 "nth period".

It’s using 4限 as a label, like “Period 4”. Similarly in English we might refer to it as “Fourth Period” as distinct from “the fourth period”.

一日の内にに4時限あります。 There are four periods in the day.

英語は4時限目です。 English is the fourth period.

4時限の後に会おう。 Let’s meet after Fourth Period.


